# How to manage directory structure of a project that uses third-party open source library?

Tags: open-source, directory-structure

I develope an open source application. Directory structure of my project is:

```
app
|-include
|-src
|-doc
|-build
|-lib
|-bin
```

I want to use another open source library. There are some choises:

- Add third-party library source code to `include` and `src` directory.
- Compile third-party library and add to `include` and `lib` directory.
- Create a `third_party` directory and add complete source code of third-party library to it.
- Create a `third_party` directory and add compiled of third-party library to it.

What is the best choise? Is there any better way to manage  directory structure of a project that uses third-party open source library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- If you are **ever** planning to upgrade the third-party library, it will be much more convenient to keep it in a specific subdirectory. You don't have to have a specific "third-party" directory; you could name it after the library.
- Think about what goes in version control.

  - If you are copying the third-party library into your *repository*, then you **SHOULD NOT** include compiled products (using source instead), as they are typically impossible to diff and platform-specific.
  - If the user is going to obtain the library separately and add it to your project's tree, then using a subdirectory will make it easier to unarchive and guarantee there won't be any name conflicts; source versus binary should be left up to the user.
  - At the other extreme, if you are using a reference your VCS manages (such as SVN externals or Git submodules), you will probably *have* to include the source in a subdirectory.

Answer (score 2):

One concern you should bear in mind, depending on your situation, is whether you will someday have to account for those third party open source components and compliance with the licenses etc.. It can be easier to manage this kind of thing if you keep the third party files in their own directories. Having the unmodified source code and licenses handy and a link back to where you got the source code and could get it again would be useful as well. I've worked at companies where there were license compliance verification processes that were easier to get through if the third party sources were segregated in this fashion.

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/234511/what-is-the-best-practice-for-arranging-third-party-library-licenses-paperwork is relevant on this.